# Is it possible to auto import JS files for all react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, auto

I have created a logging utility function that I plan to use on 99% of components in my site. I am wondering if it is possible to access this file without having to write "import { logger } from 'utils/logging';" for every React component? Sort of like an auto import?

I am using create-react-app.

Comment: What do you mean by auto import?

Comment: @CRayen: Instead of writing "import { logger } from 'utils/logging';" for every component, it would be handy if I could reference the utility file/function somewhere once and  have it accessible in all components.

Comment: See my updated answer. There is no such thing as auto-import but there are globals.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly, you want the similar usage of console.log (without importing console), then below is something you can try.

In your index file, set it as a `global` object(for server side js) or `window` object (for client side js). So that , it can be accessed anywhere.

We had something like this with a mmiddleware(using [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) package):

```
const logger = require('redux-logger').createLogger

return middleware.concat(logger({
  collapsed: true,
  duration: true
}))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes my logging is all about spitting out info to the console. I'm only trying to get around having to reference the utility file/function for each and every component. this kind of defeats the purpose as I would need to import 'redux-logger' for every component.

Comment: @Markie Thanks! We have achieved this by concat it to the Sagamiddleware (So root saga is the only place we import 'redux-logger')

Comment: @CRayen That's cool, but don't you then have to reference it in the export statement?

Comment: @MarkieB in our case, sagamiddleware `const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()` took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds like a bad way to do it. I think the best solution if you need custom data logged, would be to create/add a middleware. Or in React's case maybe a wrapper component. I'm not sure.

Otherwise look into React / Redux Dev Tools Extension.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

Edit:
If you want to ignore good practices then you can do this:

```
// in index.js or app.js or wherever
import { logger } from 'utils/logging'

// if you have an env for development use it here
process.NODE_ENV = 'development' && window.logger = logger

// or just
window.logger = logger


// SomeComponent.js
window.logger()
```